# VIEW is not attached to window manager

Tags: android, exception

i am developing an app in which there are four tabs..in each doing seperate operations.in the final tab when the operation is finished.the appliction is refreshed.

the problem is when app refreshed window leakage error is obtained.view not attached to window manager.the error is shown in the line

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                populateSpinner();
            }
```

exactly at pDialog.dismiss();

the main components of the  activity is shown below

```
public class DayStartActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new Getdata().execute();

    //  new GetRouteoptmdata().execute();
    }
private class Getdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DayStartActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("ON PROCESS..PLEASE WAIT..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_DAYSTARTDATA,
                    ServiceHandler.POST);


            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    if(json.contains("<!--"))

                        json=json.substring(0, json.indexOf("<!--"));
                    Log.e("Response according to Gettabledata:: ", " " + json);
                    // JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    // if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray daystartdata = new JSONArray(json);
                    // .getJSONArray("categories");

                    for (int i = 0; i < daystartdata.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = daystartdata
                                .getJSONObject(i);

                        DaystartSetGet daystart = new DaystartSetGet(
                                jsonChildNode.getString("altroutecode"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("route"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("salesrep"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("name"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("date"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("time"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("deleverydate"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("week"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("day"),
                                jsonChildNode.getString("vehiclenumber"));

                        routecodelist.add(daystart);

                    }
                    // }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

when the app is running for the first time there is no problem. the problem occurs when the tabs are refreshed.

please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

is the activity still on the foreground, and you don't open any new activity?

also, have you considered using a ViewSwitcher on the container of the tabs, instead of a dialog ? google suggests avoiding dialogs (especially ProgressDialog ) whenever possible : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

if you wish to still use a ProgressDialog, think of all the possible states that the dialog should be dismissed : activity being destroyed, asyncTask being cancelled (which should should at least happen when the activity is being destroyed and when the user cancels the dialog, depending on the logic of your app).